# How to redirect grep to a while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep

Hi I have the following bash script code

```
group2=0
    while read -r line
    do
      popAll=$line | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1 | tr -cd "," | wc -c
        if [[ $popAll = 0 ]]; then
          group2 = $((group2+2)); 
        else
          group2 = $((group2+popAll+1));
        fi
    done << (grep -w "token" "$file")
```

and I get the following error:

```
./parsingTrace: line 153: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./parsingTrace: line 153: `done << (grep -w "pop" "$file")'
```

I do not want to pipe grep to the while, because I want variable inside the loop to be visible outside

Comment: works if you move the pipe to front of while : `grep -w "token" "$file" | `...

Comment: @amdixon but then you are running everything in a subshell, which may cause problems.

Comment: remove the space `done << (grep -w "token" "$file")` between `<< (`

Comment: What does the desired line look like? There are far more efficient ways to get the length of the substring you want than that giant pipeline.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @chepner: 

Each line in the file that has the word "token" in, has the format "token {a,b,...}". I want to get his line and count the number of elements in each {} for each one. So I count the number of commas essentially

Comment: `[[ $line =~ token\ {(.*)}]]; commas=${BASH_REMATCH[1]//[^,]}; popall=$((1+${#commas}))`.

Comment: Thank you @chepner. I will try this out!

Comment: @luoluo no, this is not the issue here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
done << (grep -w "token" "$file")
#    ^^
```

You need to say `<` and then `<()`. The first one is to indicate the input for the `while` loop and the second one for the [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
done < <(grep -w "token" "$file")
#    ^ ^
```

Note however that there are many others things you want to check. See the comments for a discussion and paste the code in [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) for more details. Also, by indicating some sample input and desired output I am sure we can find a better way to do this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. This worked. Can you please explain me a bit the theory behind this? Also I am now getting: "./parsingTrace: line 151: group2: command not found", line 151 is "group2 = $((group2+popAll+1));"

Comment: Ths is because of the line `popAll=$line | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1 | tr -cd "," | wc -c`, which is wrong. You need to indicate what you want to do here and give some examples.

Comment: Each line in the file that has the word "token"  in, has the format "token {a,b,...}". I want to get his line and count the number of elements in each {} for each one. So I count the number of commas essentially

Comment: @KKK Then you probably want to say `popAll=$(echo "$line| ... )` instead. Also, you are saying `if [[ $popAll = 0 ]]`, but for integers we need `-eq` to compare: `if [[ "$popAll" -eq 0 ]]` ...

Comment: Now I am getting the error on line 149 "group2 = $((group2+2));", "./parsingTrace: line 149: group2: command not found"

Comment: @KKK because variable assignments cannot have spaces around the `=` use instead: `group2=$((group2+2))`

Comment: Thank you a lot...you solved all my problems. I am newbie to advance bash scripting. Any good ways to speedup knowledge?

Comment: @KKK keep trying and keep asking : ) Read http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php and also reading questions/answers here in [SO] is very useful. Happy programming!